# Is it possible to store 8 bytes in single command

Tags: c++, intel, intrinsics

I'm writing a real time code, so time is matter

I'm using C++ Intel instincts

I wonder whether is it possible to store 8 unsigned char (8 bytes) in single command instead of using a loop ?

```
char* buff = foo(); 
for (auto i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
{
    buff[i] = 0x00; 
}
```

Looking for something similar to

```
_mm256_store_ps(...)
```

I thought of doing this, but this doesn't work (I don't know why)

```
_int64* buff = foo(); 
*buff = 0x00000000;
```

Any suggestions for faster code ?

Comment: Please, post a [MCVE]. In code you posted even first snippet does not work and causes UB.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: It's pretty clear what the question is. How can someone post an MCVE when they don't know how to accomplish their goal? There is no MCVE yet.

Comment: If you're using x86-64, you can accomplish this with `xor eax, eax; mov rax, qword [mem];` - if you're stuck with x86, use MMX : `pxor mm0, mm0; movq mm0, [mem]`.

Comment: Your pointer example doesn't work because the pointer doesn't actually point anywhere. Try e.g. `uint64_t buff = 0` instead. Viola, there you have eight bytes stored in 64 bits of data in one single go, with all bits instantaneously set to zero. If that obvious solution isn't what you're looking for, maybe you better try to explain what the actual problem you try to solve is?

Comment: I don't know how to write in assembly, I'll complete my code soon

Comment: @TripleS : if you use @JoachimPileborg 's advice, you won't have to. The compiler will probably assemble storing a `uint64_t` as a 64-bit `mov`. You could also just use `memset` and not worry about anything.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: Better: `xorps xmm0, xmm0` / `movq [mem], xmm0`.  Then you don't need an `emms`.  Requires SSE2, or you could use `movlps [mem], xmm0` to do a 64-bit store with SSE1 only.  On pre-MMX, you could use x87: `fldz` / `fstp qword [mem]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an intrinsic because ordinary integer instructions are the most efficient way to store zeros in 8bit, 16bit, 32bit, or 64bit increments.

```
char* buff = foo();
*((uint64_t*)buff) = 0;
```

Since `char*` can alias anything, this is safe.  But it's *not* safe if `buff` has a different type, like `short *`.

Comment: Yes, undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar - be careful here; `char*` is allowed alias other types. You should explain why you think this leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @rustyx - um, this is **code**, and what it does depends on what the **compiler** does with it, which, in turn, depends on what the language definition says that the code should do. Yes, compilers for particular architectures may do what you would like in particular cases, but the target architecture is not the sole determinant of what a particular code snippet does.

Comment: There isn't a single x86_64 compiler with which this won't work. But by all means, use `memset` if you wish. (But then you better check the generated assembly code).

Comment: @rustyx -- asserting that this always works doesn't make it true. As you said in reply to my answer: "It _is_ really critical, as OP stated. So he'd better check the code, and recheck it every time he updates his compiler."

Comment: I checked the disassembly, I found this code much faster, thank you

Comment: @PeteBecker: I edited this answer to add some text around the code explaining why it's good and the special condition that makes it safe, since I agree it seriously needed to add that caveat.  BTW, I agree with rustyx that this is almost certain to compile to a `mov qword [buff], 0` on pretty much any compiler.  IDK if any optimizing compilers would fail to inline such an 8 byte `memset` here, but it's more possible than with this.

Comment: Downvoted for the incorrect assertion that you can alias anything.  I think you're talking about unaligned stores.  That's target-dependent, but alias analysis is compiler dependent, not target dependent.  An assignment to a `short[]` through a `int64_t*` might not "show up" when you read the `short[]` right after, since the compiler is allowed to assume that dereferencing an `int64_t*` doesn't modify an array of `short`.

Comment: You might still want to say something about unaligned accesses, though.  That's a good point that this will fault on the unaligned access on architectures like SPARC, if the `char*` isn't 8-byte aligned.

Answer (score 4):

Let the compiler worry about the best way to do it:

```
memset(buff, 0, 8);
```

Of course, if this is really critical, look at the code that it generates.

Comment: It *is* really critical, as OP stated. So he'd better check the code, and recheck it every time he updates his compiler.

Comment: @rustyx: mh, a code such that clearing 8 bytes is the most critical operation sounds dubious.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: yes, but an actual byte-loop doing it could legitimately have been a problem.  Still, that's probably a sign of bigger problems with use of intrinsics.

Answer (score 1):

When optimizing, always start by looking at what the compiler does.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdint>

extern char* foo();

char* f1() {
  char* buf = foo();
  for (auto i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    buf[i] = 0;
  return buf;
}

char* f2() {
  char* buf = foo();
  memset(buf, 0, 8);
  return buf;
}

char* f3() {
  char* buf = foo();
  *((uint64_t*)buf) = 0ULL;
  return buf;
}
```

Compiled with GCC with -O3, the output from each of the above is a single instruction for storing the 0s:

Demo on [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-O3+-m64+-std%3Dc%2B%2B14',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXATuA5gOgAsA%2BAKFElkVQkznAzNIQA8MEswkJCBDLAFRIAZgHtRACgCUAblKke/IcICM0pAG9SSbn0FIARjGFIAvCPHS5OsViQTeMDKKQgzSAAwzXqJAA5vAGpAkCltHUNjAG0QAF13L3CsBAwYTkjhOQBfeUV9YQAmdS0dPKEjE3MxSVlwgFsEOrQUiQqAGk8Ov1qdZNT0iuzcvWUAZmLwsoz3aqtwgQkJGAYANgAWAH0MASkKqQSAVQAZI%2BskPrSuQdIsoA)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

```
f1():
        subq    $8, %rsp
        call    foo()
        movq    $0, (%rax)  ; << Here
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
f2():
        subq    $8, %rsp
        call    foo()
        movq    $0, (%rax)  ; << Here
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
f3():
        subq    $8, %rsp
        call    foo()
        movq    $0, (%rax)  ; << Here
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

Comment: [You should use non-shortened godbolt urls in posts, since they can't rot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319594/224132).  Only use shortened in comments

Comment: @PeterCordes Updated